# Why is my SQL query in which I am doing a MAX and ORDER BY in 2 tables taking a long time

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Hi I do not know a whole lot about SQL this is definitely one of my weak points. this is an Oracle DB.

I have 2 tables:

```
TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE:
ID  | ORIGIN   | DESTINATION | TAXI_NUMBER |  STOPS   | DAY_OF_OPERATION | INSERT_DATE
123  NORTH AVE   CAMPBELL      1552          1W;2T;4Y   01-FEB-20          27-DEC-19
124  LEMMON AVE  HENRY ST      1511          1R;5G;P3   02-FEB-20          25-DEC-19
```

---

```
TAXI_FARE_TABLE:
ID  | ORIGIN   | DESTINATION | TAXI_NUMBER |  STOPS   |  FARE_TYPE | FARE_TYPE_AVAIL 
123  NORTH AVE   CAMPBELL      1552          1W;2T;4Y      SENIOR        5             
123  NORTH AVE   CAMPBELL      1552          1W;2T;4Y      STUDENT       10            
123  NORTH AVE   CAMPBELL      1552          1W;2T;4Y      EMPLOYEE      10            
124  LEMMON AVE  HENRY ST      1511          1R;5G;P3      SENIOR        5             
124  LEMMON AVE  HENRY ST      1511          1R;5G;P3      STUDENT       3             
124  LEMMON AVE  HENRY ST      1511          1R;5G;P3      EMPLOYEE      10
```

**TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE INDEX:**

```
STOPS, TAXI_NUMBER, DESTINATION, ORIGIN, DAY_OF_OPERATION

CREATE INDEX "TAXI_ADMIN"."IX01_TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE" ON 
"TAXI_ADMIN"."TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE" ("STOPS", "TAXI_NUMBER", "DESTINATION", 
"ORIGIN", "DAY_OF_OPERATION ") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "TAXI_ADMIN" ;
```

**TAXI_FARE_TABLE** does not have any indexes.

**These tables have millions of records in them**. the same records are in both tables its just that the taxi fare table has them repeated due to the types of fares for each taxi.

so I am trying to do a join to be able to get all the **most recently inserted** records and the fare types for them. So I should only get back the records inserted on 27-DEC-19.

**My problem:** my query is maxing out the time limit, its taking forever. I would really appreciate your guidance on this.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT R.ID,
       R.ORIGIN,
       R.DESTINATION,
       R.TAXI_NUMBER,
       R.STOPS,
       R.DAY_OF_OPERATION,
       R.INSERT_DATE,
       F.FARE_TYPE,
       F.FARE_TYPE_AVAIL
FROM TAXI_ADMIN.TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE R, TAXI_ADMIN.TAXI_FARE_TABLET F

WHERE INSERT_DATE = (SELECT MAX(INSERT_DATE) FROM TAXI_ADMIN.TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE)

AND R.ID = F.ID

ORDER BY R.ORIGIN, R.DESTINATION, R.DAY_OF_OPERATION;
```

I am not sure how can I make the query faster. When I run without the order by its pretty quick but the order by takes a really long time.

thank you

Comment: Are there any indexes on the tables?  It sounds like the columns referenced in the ORDER BY clause are not a part of an index.  That would explain why it is taking so much longer with the ORDER BY clause.  It could be performing seek operations (fast) without the ORDER BY, but scan operations (slow) without the ORDER BY.

Comment: `INSERT_DATE` in the `WHERE` clause isn't qualified and therefore ambiguous. So this query will error out. Please [edit] the question and add the tables's full DLL (`CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements), the **real** query and the explain plan with the real query.

Comment: Hi thank you guys for replying. Sticky bit sorry I completely missed that the second table does not have the column INSERT_DATE just took it off. The TAXI_FARE_TABLE does not have any indexes but the TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE had the index I just posted

Comment: added index sql statement not sure if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query (which I've cleaned up a bit):

```
SELECT R.ID, R.ORIGIN, R.DESTINATION, R.TAXI_NUMBER,
       R.STOPS, R.DAY_OF_OPERATION, R.INSERT_DATE,
       F.FARE_TYPE, F.FARE_TYPE_AVAIL
FROM TAXI_ADMIN.TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE R JOIN 
     TAXI_ADMIN.TAXI_FARE_TABLET F
     ON R.ID = F.ID
WHERE R.INSERT_DATE = (SELECT MAX(R2.INSERT_DATE) FROM TAXI_ADMIN.TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE R2)
ORDER BY R.ORIGIN, R.DESTINATION, R.DAY_OF_OPERATION;
```

You want indexes on: `TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE(INSERT_DATE, ID)` and `TAXI_FARE_TABLET(ID)`.  It is hard to eliminate the overhead for the `ORDER BY`.  So if there is a lot of data, this may not help a lot.

If Oracle is smart enough, then extending the first index to `TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE(INSERT_DATE, ORIGIN, DESTINATION, DAY_OF_OPERATION, ID)` would help.  This is an interesting optimization, because it would need to take the `ORDER BY` into account before doing the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend identifying the SQL id for the query then using the SQL Monitor Report as it will tell you exactly what the execution plan is and where the SQL is spending most of it's time.

A simple way to get the SQL Monitor Report from SQL*Plus follows:

```
spool c:\temp\SQL_Monitor_rpt.html

SET LONG 1000000
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 1000000
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIM ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF

alter session set "_with_subquery" = optimizer;

SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.report_sql_monitor(
  sql_id       => '&SQLID' ,
  type         => 'HTML',
  report_level => 'ALL') AS report
FROM dual;

spool off
```

Also, in this case you probably need three more indexes:
TAXI_ADMIN.TAXI_ROUTES_TABLE.INSERT_DATE to cover the subset condition
and the ID column on both tables to cover the join condition